# iOS - Core Data : standard deviation

Tags: ios, core-data, standard-deviation

I've used the NSExpression method expressionForFunction:arguments: with success for average, sum, min, max, count, with the same code than below (given in Apple's documentation).

But when it comes to standard deviation (stddev:) or median (median:). I don't have errors while compiling but I simply get "SIGABRT" signal on the executeFetchRequest line.

I can't find out what should be the difference between average, sum, min, max, count and stddev or median, in my code. The NSExpression class doesn't make a difference between parameters and return object of these, only difference is availability (Mac OS 10.4 for those which are working, 10.5 for the others.

I'm using Xcode 4.2, and my app is targetting iOS 5 with ARC.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"myEntity" inManagedObjectContext:app.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"something == %d",2]];

// Specify that the request should return dictionaries.
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

// Create an expression for the key path.
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"anAttribute"];

// Create an expression to represent the minimum value at the key path
NSExpression *statExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"stddev:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

// Create an expression description using the statExpression and returning a float.
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

// The name is the key that will be used in the dictionary for the return value.
[expressionDescription setName:@"statData"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:statExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSFloatAttributeType];

// Set the request's properties to fetch just the property represented by the expressions.
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];

// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [app.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (objects == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}
float result = [[[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"statData"] floatValue];
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: According to the availability table, if you're targeting iOS, *none* of the functions you have tested should have worked. The table shows no overlap between iOS and Mac OS at all -- very weird. Sounds like the table is wrong, and min max etc. are actually available to iOS, but not stddev, so you're stuck performing that analysis yourself.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Even in .h there's no info, no comment about it, the table of args is there too, in comment, but no minimum version on it either.